# Next.js custom typescript server

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have a monorepo with two next.js apps. And common libs for this two apps. I need custom server to handle locale routes. Do custom server and run with ts-node like in example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-typescript

But can't import smth outside of next.js app with error:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file
```

How can I create custom server and import some typescript modules outside of next.js directory ?

Comment: Please include a minimal example that has the stated problem with the question.
Anyways it looks like you are importing from a module that does not have emitted js files

Comment: Please don't use a custom server to handle locale routes, you definitely don't need it nowadays with i18n routing (except if you have a very good reason, in which case you might want to elaborate in your question, most probably you were using a version pre 10 at the time of writing). 50% of questions on Next.js are about custom servers: that's because they are source of complexity, additional setup, and various bugs, so you may want to assess if you need them.